# How to create Index pattern using API and Index Name

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I created Indices by Elasticsearch API, to create visualization I need the index pattern ID of that particular index. Is there a possible way to create an index pattern using API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create an index pattern via the [Saved Object API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/saved-objects-api-create.html).

```
$ curl -X POST <kibana-host>:<port>/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/index-pattern-id  -H 'kbn-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
  "attributes": {
    "title": "my-index-*"
  }
}'
```

Comment: After doing this, the index pattern shows up in the corresponding GET response, but I still don't see it in the UI

Comment: @naraghi please create a new thread explaining your current issue

Comment: Never mind. I had to disable OpenSearch's security plugin to access the API